# jq: error: $i is not defined at <top-level>

Tags: json, loops, for-loop, jq, variable-assignment

Im doing a bash script where I use a for loop in order to get some information using a AWS command, the output of the command is a list in Json so, i'm using jq for filtering the response. As I'm expecting to pass the output of the first command to another i need to send each element of the list individually and here is where I'm in troubles.

```
for i in {0..1}
do
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $1 --profile $2 | jq '.taskArns[$i]'
done
```

It doesn't matter how I set the for, if I set it as for i in {0..1} or for i in "${tasks[@]}" when I run the script it give back the same error, however if I put the index as taskArns[0] or taskArns[1] the script works.

Thanks in Advice!

Answer (score 4):

You never set the jq var `$i` before using it. You could do so as follows:

```bash
jq --arg i "$i" '.taskArns[ $i | tonumber ]'
```

---

You might want to move the loop into `jq` to avoid calling `aws` twice.

```bash
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $1 --profile $2 | jq '.taskArns[0:2][]'
```

Comment: In this case, you'll want to use `--argjson` and not `--arg` so it's typed as a number and not a string.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado Fixed

Comment: It may also be worth noting that '$i' is never set because single quotes are used for the jq filter strings (as expected). With single quotes, `$i` is treated as a literal `$i`, rather than being substituted for the variable `i` in the for loop (which would be the case if double quotes were used).